# GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver with OWIN

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, unity-container, asp.net-web-api2, owin

Now that we are using OWIN middleware, I understand that `GlobalConfiguration` should be avoided.

Previously, I was using the service locator (anti) pattern to inject concrete repositories into Web API validation filters.  For example:

```
public class UniqueEmployeeNameAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public IEmployeeRepository EmployeeRepository { get; set; }

    public UniqueEmployeeNameAttribute ()
        : base("Employee name must be unique.")
    {
        EmployeeRepository = (IEmployeeRepository)GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IEmployeeRepository));
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if(value == null) { return true; }

        return !EmployeeRepository.HasName(value.ToString().Trim());
    }
}
```

When using OWIN, `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver` is now an `EmptyResolver` (`System.Web.Http.Dependencies.EmptyResolver`).

How would I achieve the above when using OWIN middleware?

Comment: Can you please show the snippet where you config WebAPI in your Startup-Class.

Comment: Hi, I am using Ninject and i updated my nuget packages and GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver started returning EmptyResolver. :-(.   I have changed it to DependencyResolver.Current and it now returns a NinjectDependencyResolver and works again.

Comment: DependencyResolver.Current from what other object? I'm in the same situation and can't figure out from where to call that dependency resolver you are mentioning...